# PayPal-Ruby-SDK web-experience-profile creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, paypal

I am a bit of a new rails developer and I am not making sense of Paypal's documentation to [create a web experience profile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-experience-overview/#create-the-web-experience-profile) before processing a payment with the REST API:

I can make payments ok with code below as long as I do not try to use the experience profile.

When debugging, I get a value for @webprofile similar to:

```
#<PayPal::SDK::REST::DataTypes::WebProfile:0x007fe0f9344e50 @error=nil, 
@name="YeowZa! T-Shirt Shop", @presentation=#<PayPal::SDK::REST::DataTypes::Presentation:0x007fe0f8ec51b8 @error=nil, @brand_name="YeowZa! Paypa
l", @logo_image="http://www.yeowza.com", @locale_code="US">, @input_fields=#<PayPal::SDK::REST::DataTypes::InputFields:0x007fe0f927b0f0 @error=nil, @allow_note=true, @no_shipping=0, @address_override=1>, @flow_config
=#<PayPal::SDK::REST::DataTypes::FlowConfig:0x007fe0f90808e0 @error=nil, @landing_page_type="billing", @bank_txn_pending_url="http://www.yeowza.com">, @request_id="bcc4bc41-b61c-4d28-94f1-a0912121d8e8", @header={}>
```

On my console I see:
Request[post]: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payment-experience/web-profiles/
Response[400]: Bad Request,

My code so far is:

```
class PaypalController < ApplicationController
  require 'paypal-sdk-rest'
  include PayPal::SDK::REST
  include PayPal::SDK::Core::Logging

  def create 
    PayPal::SDK::REST.set_config(
    :mode => "sandbox", # "sandbox" or "live"
    :client_id => "my-id",
    :client_secret => "my-secret")

    # Build Payment object
    @payment = Payment.new({ 

      :intent => "sale",
      :payer => {
      :payment_method => "paypal"},
      :experience_profile_id => self.web_experience,
      :redirect_urls => {
        :return_url => "http://me.com/paypal_complete",
        :cancel_url => "http://me.com/paypal_cancel"},

        :transactions => [{
          :item_list => {
            :items => [{
              :name => "me.com Thing",
              :sku => "the-specific-horse",
              :price => "2",
              :currency => "USD",
              :quantity =>  "1" }]},
          :amount => {
            :total => "2.00",
            :currency => "USD" },
          :description => "Payment for the-specific-thing" }]
        })

      # Create Payment and return the status(true or false)
    if @payment.create
      # Redirect the user to given approval url
      @redirect_url = @payment.links.find{|v| v.method == "REDIRECT" }.href
      logger.info "Payment[#{@payment.id}]"
      logger.info "Redirect: #{@redirect_url}"
      redirect_to @redirect_url
    else
      logger.error @payment.error.inspect
    end
  end

  def paypal_complete
    begin
      # paymentId: PAY-8L3183743T450642VKWDPH7I
      # token: EC-57E34614K6825515M
      # PayerID: RBWLMFNFF4ZUC
      payment_id = params[:paymentId]
      # Retrieve the payment object by calling the
      # `find` method
      # on the Payment class by passing Payment ID
      @payment = Payment.find(payment_id)
      logger.info "Got Payment Details for Payment[#{@payment.id}]"

    rescue ResourceNotFound => err
      # It will throw ResourceNotFound exception if the payment not found
      logger.error "Payment Not Found"
    end
  end

  def web_experience
    #this is not used right now...don't know how
    @webprofile = WebProfile.new(
        {
        :name => "YeowZa! T-Shirt Shop",
        :presentation => {
            :brand_name => "YeowZa! Paypal",
            :logo_image => "http://www.yeowza.com",
            :locale_code => "US"
        },
        :input_fields => {
            :allow_note => true,
            :no_shipping => 0,
            :address_override => 1
        },
        :flow_config => {
            :landing_page_type => "billing",
            :bank_txn_pending_url => "http://www.yeowza.com"
        }
        })  

        if @webprofile.create
          # Redirect the user to given approval url

          logger.info "@webprofile[#{@webprofile}]"
          debugger
        else
          logger.error @payment.error.inspect
          debugger
        end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I thought others might end up here like I did.

I had a similar issue with the .NET SDK. Resolved by removing fields from the request object that I shouldn't have been using i.e. the field bank_txn_pending_url I had set to an empty string, when I didn't define this field at all (which would equate to null), the request returned 200. It clearly states in the documentation that this field should only be used in Germany in certain circumstances.

Once created though, subsequent requests fail, because you cannot have two profiles with the same name. You need to get the list of existing profiles and use the existing ID if found. No need to create over and over.

Bummer the dashboard doesn't capture all requests in the transaction section, would make life much easier if it did.